# Should I use registry cleaners?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-registry, regedit

I have a computer that has had some registry issues.  I repaired my Windows installation, however I would like to ensure that there aren't any more issues.  I read that you can use this method by [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307545).  However, I do not want to use this method unless I know something is still wrong.

Does anyone have any suggestions for a registry cleaner or scanner?

Comment: In which other community would this question be on topic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you never use registry cleaners. If your computer is running fine at the moment, don't mess with the registry. The risk of a serious problem caused by a registry cleaner erroneously
removing an entry you need is far greater than any potential benefit it may have. I recommend you reading [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/what-registry-cleaner-is-the-best-for-windows/552a8c56-bd03-4681-89d1-b49a19621a2c) thread from Microsoft Answers. Furthermore, Mark Russinovich's article about "[Registry Junk: A Windows Fact of Life](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-blog-archive/registry-junk-a-windows-fact-of-life/ba-p/723422)" gives some insight on Windows registry and registry cleaners.

Comment: I've heard that arguement before.  Many people claim that any regcleaner is a scam (ie regcure).  I just wanted know about other people's experience with them.  I'll check out those links.

Comment: Both links are dead unfortunately.

Comment: Fixed the 2nd link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Trend Micro [HijackThis](http://free.antivirus.com/hijackthis/), it is a free utility that generates an in depth report of registry and file settings from your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I use the simple reg clean that is part of CCleaner.  Delete obvious dead stuff caused by updates, but don't get clever or fancy.  Since it does' t mess with things that affect booting, it should be possible to restore if you ended up having a problem.  I've never had an incedent with that.